# Newtheoremstyle, newline and enumerate

Tags: vertical-alignment

Consider the following code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{multiple_remarks}
  {1.0em}
  {1.0em}
  {\normalfont}
  {0pt}
  {\bfseries}
  { : \\}
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  {}

\theoremstyle{multiple_remarks}
\newtheorem*{remarks}{Remarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{remarks}
        Test.
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First item.
          \item Second item.
          \item Fourth item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{remarks}

    \begin{remarks}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First item.
          \item Second item.
          \item Fourth item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{remarks}
\end{document}
```

**Question:** Why the list doesn't begin on the line after the remarks header like it does for normal text, and how to fix this?

Comment: For me the second environment begins on the same line as the header.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I want it to begin on the line after, like the first environment.

Comment: Insert an `\mbox{}` before the first item — or use  `ntheorem`: it has several ‘break’ styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that right after `\begin{remarks}` TeX is in vertical mode; using `\leavevmode` (and a possible negative vertical spacing), for example, solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{multiple_remarks}
  {1.0em}
  {1.0em}
  {\normalfont}
  {0pt}
  {\bfseries}
  {:}
  {\newline}
  {}

\theoremstyle{multiple_remarks}
\newtheorem*{remarks}{Remarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{remarks}
        Test.
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First item.
          \item Second item.
          \item Fourth item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{remarks}

    \begin{remarks}\leavevmode
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First item.
          \item Second item.
          \item Fourth item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{remarks}

       \begin{remarks}\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item First item.
          \item Second item.
          \item Fourth item.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{remarks} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But why the second `enumerate` is too lower? Is there an empty line before it?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Is there a way to "integrate" the `\leavevmode` directly in the `remarks` environment so as not to have to type `\leavevmode` every time ? Doesn't seem to work when I put it alongside the `:` character or if I replace `\newline` by it.

Comment: @Amateur since a vertical spacing will be needed (see my updated answer), I think there's no point in incorporating the command directly. In any case, you could try something like `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\leavevmode}`.

Comment: @Amateur but I wouldn't do that anyway; I'd go with the manual adjustment when required.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Okay, thank you. I asked this because my `remarks` environment will always begin with a list. For a unique remark I will have a `remark` environment. But in the end maybe it's just easier to type "remark" and "remarks" every time since I don't enumerate my remarks...

Comment: @Amateur Ah, in that case, it's better to say `\newenvironment{rema}
  {\begin{remarks}\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}\end{remarks}}` and then use it as    `\begin{rema}
          \item First item.
          \item Second item.
          \item Third item.
    \end{rema}`